# HTML menu navigation menu with horizontal slides

Tags: javascript, html, menubar

I need 3 level menu bar like this:
[image: image link]

User will select 3 different options from the menu.
in this example the target url will be like this:
www.mysite.com/show.php?type=cat&size=middle&color=yellow

The url will be opened as soon as user changes one option in the menubar.

I don't have experience to make this menu from scratch,
is there any ready scripts making similar behaviour,
or which terms do you recommend me search for in javascrpt forums?
Thank you

Comment: Does the sub elements depends of the elements of the higher level. eg: When you select bird, do you have `small, middle, big` or `slow, fast, whatever`

Comment: @pinouchon now i don't have any dependency between the sub levels. all animals can be any color and any size. but in future maybe that dependency "may" be important.

Comment: You really should handle it now, so you wont have trouble later